# Issues when writing an image

Tags: java-me

Am into an J2ME project right now where I need to select an image and write this image to a particular folder say somewhere in memory card with a desired file name. Am able to select image and display it but when trying to save it am having trouble. When I try to save, an image file is created but its size is 0.0 kb and when I click on the image it says "File Format not supported"

This is my code

```
fileCon =  (FileConnection)Connector.open(path+"Contacts/contactImages/"+FIRST_NAME+".png",Connector.READ_WRITE);   
if(!fileCon.exists())
 {
     fileCon.create();
 }

int h = contactImage.getHeight();
int w = contactImage.getWidth();

int[] size = new int[w*h];
contactImage.getRGB(size, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

for (int i = 0; i < size.length; i++) 
 {
     dos.writeInt(size[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

But you are writing pixel data into (in-memory) ByteArrayOutputStream, and not a file stream. Shouldn't there be something like

DataOutputStream dos = fileCon.openDataOutputStream();

And of course output stream should be closed to make sure all data is flushed.

Another thing is that you are saving raw ARGB data and not encoded PNG image, so .png extension may confuse some image viewers. Perhaps .bmp would be better.